# Is this sentence correctly done?

Tags: sentence

"I'm never being ironic."

or should it be "I'm never ironic."

?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the correct answer here would be "I'm never ironic."  The first isn't technically wrong, it's just not as natural.  A specific case where it could be used would be something like:

A: "Aren't you just being ironic?"
B: "I'm never 'just being ironic'."

or something like that, but even in that case, B could have said (and probably even most naturally say) something like "I'm never ironic."

Answer (score 0):

"Are you being ironic?" or "He was being ironic" both sound natural but the negative usage
*"I'm never being ironic"* does not sound like idiomatic English, at least not to this Midwest American native English speaker.

Comment: "I am never being ironic." may not be *idiomatic*, however OP is asking whether or not the sentence is *gramatically sound*, which it is.